# How can I find the active child window?

Tags: .net, winforms

How can I find the active child window (like focus Edit in modal dialog). I know how to enumerate child windows, but I don't know how to detect if a child window is active (focus).

Comment: rashim, please pay a little attention to the tags. C# does not have Windows. The Windows.Forms library does.

Comment: Did any answer help You? Please mark the answer You chose

Answer (score 2):

I have got an answer after trying more than 2 hour with google. This is what I've got :

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(500);
int foregroundWindowHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
uint remoteThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(foregroundWindowHandle, 0);
uint currentThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();      
//AttachTrheadInput is needed so we can get the handle of a focused window in another app
AttachThreadInput(remoteThreadId, currentThreadId, true);
//Get the handle of a focused window
int focused = GetFocus();
//Now detach since we got the focused handle
AttachThreadInput(remoteThreadId, currentThreadId, false);
```

As we have the handle of the focus window we could get it name/Class and also other necessary information

In this case I just find out the class name:

```
StringBuilder winClassName = new StringBuilder();
int numChars = CustomViewAPI.Win32.GetClassName((IntPtr)focused, winClassName, 
winClassName.Capacity);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically it's just a simple Linq query:

```
      var active = (from form in Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form>()
                    where form.Focused
                    select form).FirstOrDefault();
```

Where active can be null or a form. Just a short example with few forms:

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      Form sample = new Form();
      sample.Text = i.ToString();
      sample.Show();
    }

    while (true)
    {
      var active = (from form in Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form>()
                    where form.Focused
                    select form).FirstOrDefault();

      if (active != null)
        Console.Write(active.Text);

      Application.DoEvents();
      Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: This one has my vote.  IMO, the query looks a little better in fluent syntax for this one: 
Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form>()
.FirstOrDefault(f=>f.Focused)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the active child window of a different process, then you can match the IntPtr to the child window to the IntPtr from

```
  [DllImport("User32")]
  public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

If this is not what you are looking for, could you please elaborate a little on your problem.

Comment: Actually I am working with the Modal Dialog. In this case it first focus the address bar. If we press tab then it focuses on the Edit box. So i would like to know how should i detect which control window has focused right now?

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking about Mdi child windows, you can use ActiveMdiChild, which is a property of the form class (use it on your mdiparent).

If you are speaking about focused controls, you can get using  ActiveControl, which is a property of every container control (e.g. all your forms)